# Lightning listview inconsistently giving 'This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience.' ERROR

Tags: lightning, list-view

I am having an issue with a list view on an object that inconsistently displays the issue 'This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience. To see this list view, use Salesforce Classic or switch to another list view.' It is not happening in every environment and it's not happening all the time. Does anyone have a solution to it or know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ended up happening because it timed out searching through all the data. The workaround was to use an indexed field to filter so it doesn't come up with that error.

Answer (score 1):

Look into below items ,

- See if your list view filter has an apostrophe. There is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eyjBQAQ) here that looks still unsolved.
- There is a [list of the things](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_data_access.htm&type=5) that is not supported in lightning list views (check list views sub section) compared to classic. Make sure you are not hitting one of these.